# JQuery Hide function is not working

Tags: jquery

I want hide the span tag by clicking on a link but not working.

I am using following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showhide(obj) {
        $(obj).closest('tr').find('td span').hide();
        //$('.testspan').css('background-color', 'red');        }
    }
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-top: 16px float:left;" colspan="3" id="asd">
            <h3>
                <u>
                    <a class="faculty_more_des" href='javascript:showhide(this);'>Read More</a>
                </u>
            </h3>
            <span class="testspan">This is test sample </span>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the `href` handler `this` refers to the window object, so use onlick handler to call the method

```
<a class="faculty_more_des" href="#" onclick='javascript:showhide(this);'>Read More</a>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Dvp2S/)

But I prefer to use jQuery to register the event handler instead of using inline handlers

Comment: Or, even better, don't use inline JS at all but bind the event handler to the link with jQuery. Also the `javascript:` part is unnecessary in an onclick attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your code refers to the `window` object, you are loading jQuery, use it's functions:

```
$('.faculty_more_des').on('click', function(event) {
   // event.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('h3').next('.testspan').toggle();
});
```